# MSSQL Server INSERT NULL, but insert GetDate() in DATETIME

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter, datetime

I am migrating a database from MySQL to MSSQL. 
[MySQL] I have a CHANGEDATE column that is of  TIMESTAMP with default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
[MSSQL] I have the same CHANGEDATE column that is of DATETIME and added a default constraint of GETDATE()

The codebase is PHP using CodeIgniter. I want the column to always be set so I don't allow NULL in either DBMS.

When I insert with MySQL, the property of the PHP model CHANGEDATE defaults to NULL. This triggers the default and the column entry is set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. The same code when configured to MSSQL however throws an error that NULL is not allowed in the column, which is valid, but I would rather MSSQL function like MySQL and insert the value of GETDATE() in that instance.

If I do `unset($model->CHANGEDATE)` or delete the property from my model, then it works as expected, but I wanted to know if there was a way to solve this just using MSSQL instead of updating all my PHP models.

```
class model {
public $CHANGEDATE;
...
}
```

ERROR (as described):
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CHANGEDATE'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
INSERT INTO Logs (..., CHANGEDATE, CHANGEBY) VALUES (..., NULL, NULL)`

UPDATE:
CI should create support for DBMS specific keywords as @steoleary stated in his answer(for which I marked his correct). However, I found the best solution in my case was to slightly modify the core class DB_active_rec.php

```
function set(...){
...
foreach ($key as $k => $v)
{
if (is_null($v)) continue;
...
}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your table and constraint definitions for both the MySQL and SQL Server versions, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you already have the default set on your SQL server column and you don't allow NULLs, deafult constraints won't fire on a NULL value, they will only fire when no value is specified, or if you specify to insert the default value on insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table]
           ([col1]
           ,[col2]
           ,[col3]
           ,[col4]) --Column with default constraint
     VALUES
           ('bob',
           'bobson',
           1,
           DEFAULT) --default keyword
```

Doing that will cause the default to fire and you shouldn't have to change your models.

Comment: I wonder why there's a difference between behaviour in MySQL and SQL Server in this case, given that I think that's exactly how MySQL should work, too...

Comment: Thank you! This is on the right track. However, the question now is how to insert DEFAULT as a value from PHP. I am using active record. If I use quotes it assumes I am attempting to insert a string.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to express this in code igniter, but in SQL Server, it is really easy:

```
create table . . .  (
    changedate not null datetime default getdate()
)
```

No trigger is required.